# Drupal multi language and google translate

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have following situation:

- I created a multi language site in Drupal for English and German. This works perfect, with German as the main language.
- for other languages like Polish and Russian, I want to use google translate.

I installed the [Google Translate](https://www.drupal.org/project/gtrans) module and activated the needed languages. I have active the block, so I will see the languages and can translate the website.

Now I have following problem:

I have now two flags with German on the website. one from the normal translation and one from the google translate module. I want to remove the German flag from the google translate module. I could hide the flag with css, but then the website will not work as expected.

Following situation:

- I select the English flag, then the English version of the website will be shown.
- I select the Polish flag, then google translate will translate the website to polish.
- I select the German flag from Drupal, then the german url will be used, but google translate will translate the website to polish. I have click on the german flag of google translate, then the german version will be shown.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You're looking for something that resets the Google translate widget when you change the URL from one language to another. I don't think there's such a method out-of-the-box for Google Translate widget unfortunately.